# unit test about upload xls file

Tags: django

this is my test code:

```
def test_import_data(self):
       f = open('commend/fixtures/Book2.xls')
       postdata = {'datatype':'intonetwork','datafile':f}
       response = self.client.post('/commend/saledata/import_data/',postdata)
       self.failUnlessEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

but in the view code:

```
file = request.FILES['datafile']
size = file.size
```

the size only equal 6.

so i debug the Client.post code:

```
def encode_file(boundary, key, file):
   to_str = lambda s: smart_str(s, settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)
   return [
       '--' + boundary,
       'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' \
           % (to_str(key), to_str(os.path.basename(file.name))),
       'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
       '',
       file.read()
   ]
```

when i open the commend/fixtures/Book2.xls.

```
>>> f = open("commend/fixtures/Book2.xls")
>>> f.read()
```

'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1'

```
>>> f.read()
```

'\x00\xb9\xa4\xd7\xf7\xb1\xed\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0
0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0
0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0
0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\xfe\xff\x03\n\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\xff \x08\x02\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\xc0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00F#\x00\x00\x00Microsoft Office Excel 200
3 \xb9\xa4\xd7\xf7\xb1\xed\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00Biff8\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00Excel.She
et.8\x00\xf49\xb2q\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
........................

when type f.read() for the first time,output '\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1',not the entire xls document content.

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening the file in binary mode:

```
f = open('commend/fixtures/Book2.xls', 'rb')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's being read in Unicode. Just for testing, try to save the xls file in other format and see what happens. [Here](http://diveintopython.net/xml_processing/unicode.html) the issues with Unicode in python are exposed.